# How do I calculate one's retirement date?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use one's date of birth to calculate when he'll be 50, if he's not 50 already.

If person is not 50, add a year to his age  then check if it'll be 50. If not, iterate until it's true. Then get the date he turned 50. in PHP

Here's the code, not complete.

```
$rAge = 50;
$retir =  date('j F Y ', strtotime("+30 days"));
$oneMonthAdded = strtotime(date("d-m-Y", strtotime($DOB)). "+1 year");
$re = date("d-m-Y", $oneMonthAdded);
$futDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(date("d-m-Y", strtotime($re))));

$date_diff = strtotime($futDate)-strtotime($DOB);

$future_age = floor(($date_diff)/(60*60*24*365));

Help please.
```

Comment: No one here. We have all retired.

Comment: Can you please explain your query in well manner ? is there any code where you get issue ?

Comment: a) show us what you actually **tried** b) define **not working**, we can't read minds yet c) read **[how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** before doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

try this code bro!

```
    // your date of birth
    $dateOfBirth = '1950-11-26';
    // date when he'll turn 50
    $dateToFifty = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateOfBirth . '+50 Years'));
    // current date
    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
    $result = 'retired';
    // checks if already fifty
    if($currentDate <= $dateToFifty) {
        $result = $dateToFifty;
    }
    echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use simplest php code to find out retire date. y

```
<?php
      $dob = '1970-02-01';
      $dob_ex = explode("-",$dob);
      $age_diff = date_diff(date_create($dob), date_create('today'))->y;
      $year_of_retire = 50 - $age_diff;
      $end = date('Y', strtotime('+'.$year_of_retire.'years'));
      $date_of_retire = $end."-".$dob_ex[1]."-".$dob_ex[2];
      echo $date_of_retire;
    ?>
```

you can use if...else condition to echo values according to you.
like

```
if($year_of_retire > 0){
  echo $date_of_retire;
} else if($year_of_retire < 0){
  echo "retired";
}
```